# Alternatives for the word scratch

Tags: word-usage, sentence-construction, word-meaning

Is saying I got a minor scratch good enough for something like this:
[image]

The above is a very small cut with 3-4 drops of blood coming out.
I am not sure if just saying `I got a minor scratch` is enough to convey this. Because there was little blood coming out too.
What could be a more precise and concise way to convey this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

"A minor scratch" is fine. You could also say "a small cut" or "[a nick](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/nick)". (A minor cut that draws little or no blood is a "[paper cut](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Paper_cut)", but that looks a bit bigger than a paper cut.)

Comment: A paper cut should really be a cut caused by paper, whether or not blood comes out.  They are typically small and very clean cuts, and often bloodless.